# Getting the avarage value from a column in a dataframe if a column contains a string specified in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe (prices) that contains a long description and a price associated to that description.
I generated another dataframe (words) that keeps all the unique words that those long descriptions has. What I'm trying to do is to fetch the average price of a particular word from the prices dataframe and then store it in the word dataframe, in the same row that the word is.

I managed to obtain the average of a particular word, but when I tried looping through the word dataframe it takes way too much time.

This works for a single value:

```
prices.loc[prices['TEXT'].str.contains("PREMIUM", na=False)]['PRICE'].mean()
```

And this is the Loop I tried running:

```
for ind in words.index:
  words['avgs'][ind]=prices.loc[prices['TEXT'].str.contains(words['WORD'][ind], na=False)]['PRICE'].mean()
```

example dataframes:

```
prices = pd.DataFrame({'TEXT': ['VINO ESPUMOSO ROSE GRADO ALCOHOLICO 11.8 ACIDEZ VOLATIL 0.37 COSECHA 2013 EN CAJAS DE 06X750 ML SIN EMBALAR', 'VINO CON DENOMINACION DE ORIGEN ESPUMOSO SPARKLING ANGEL BRUT GRADO ALCOHOLICO 12.0 06BOTELLAS EN ENVASE DE 750 ML SIN EMBALAR', 'VINO ESPUMOSO CHARDONNAY PINOT NOIR EXTRA BR DE UVA, GR.ALC.12.80, ACIDEZ  VOL. 0.46 G/L.,CAJAS DE 6 BOLTELLAS DE 750 ML. SIN EMBALAR', 'VINO PINOT NOIR ROSE BRUT GA 12.0 AV 0.45 COSECHA 2013 CON DENOMINACION DE ORIGEN EN CAJAS CON BOTELLAS DE 6X750CC SIN EMBALAR', 'VINO ESPUMOSO ROSE GRADO ALCOHOLICO 11.8 ACIDEZ VOLATIL 0.37 COSECHA 2013 EN CAJAS DE 06X750 ML SIN EMBALAR VINO CON DENOMINACION DE ORIGEN ESPUMOSO SPARKLING ANGEL BRUT GRADO ALCOHOLICO 12.0 06BOTELLAS EN ENVASE DE 750 ML SIN EMBALAR VINO ESPUMOSO CHARDONNAY PINOT NOIR EXTRA BR DE UVA, GR.ALC.12.80, ACIDEZ  VOL. 0.46 G/L.,CAJAS DE 6 BOLTELLAS DE 750 ML. SIN EMBALAR VINO PINOT NOIR ROSE BRUT GA 12.0 AV 0.45 COSECHA 2013 CON DENOMINACION DE ORIGEN EN CAJAS CON BOTELLAS DE 6X750CC SIN EMBALAR'],
                       'PRICE': [6.33, 5.43, 2.79, 3.07, 1.96]})

words = pd.DataFrame({'WORD':['VINO', 'ESPUMOSO', 'ROSE', 'GRADO', 'ALCOHOLICO', '11.8', 'ACIDEZ', 'VOLATIL', '0.37', 'COSECHA', '2013', 'EN', 'CAJAS', 'DE', '06X750', 'ML', 'SIN', 'EMBALAR', 'CON', 'DENOMINACION', 'ORIGEN', 'SPARKLING', 'ANGEL', 'BRUT', '12.0', '06BOTELLAS', 'ENVASE', '750', 'CHARDONNAY', 'PINOT', 'NOIR', 'EXTRA', 'BR', 'UVA,', 'GR.ALC.12.80,', 'VOL.', '0.46', 'G/L.,CAJAS', '6', 'BOLTELLAS', 'ML.', 'GA', 'AV', '0.45', 'BOTELLAS', '6X750CC', ]})
```

Any way to make this code faster? 
Thanks!

Comment: Looks to me like all you need to do is prices['MeanForText']=prices.groupby('TEXT')['PRICE'].transform('mean') and slice or select each text word?

Comment: thanks for the reply, but how would you check if the word is contained in the text from the prices dataframe?

Comment: Is it possible to add small example dataframes?

Comment: Would depend, post a sample of dataframe. There are multiple ways to find out.

Comment: I posted and edit with the examples, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be to use `Series.str.extractall`, then `join` the extractions back on the `index` and finally use `GroupBy.mean`:

```
matches = (
    prices['TEXT'].str.extractall(f'({"|".join(words["WORD"])})')
    .rename(columns={0:'WORDS'})
    .rename_axis(['index', 'match'])
)

final = (
    prices.rename_axis('index')
    .join(matches)
    .groupby('WORDS', sort=False)['PRICE'].mean()
    .reset_index(name='MEAN_PRICE')
)
```

**Output**

```
print(final)
            WORDS  MEAN_PRICE
0            VINO    3.182500
1        ESPUMOSO    3.405000
2            ROSE    3.330000
3           GRADO    3.920000
4      ALCOHOLICO    3.920000
5            11.8    4.145000
6          ACIDEZ    3.260000
7         VOLATIL    4.145000
8            0.37    4.145000
9         COSECHA    3.330000
10           2013    3.330000
11             EN    3.512500
12          CAJAS    3.330000
13             DE    2.990000
14         06X750    4.145000
15             ML    3.405000
16            SIN    3.182500
17        EMBALAR    3.182500
18            CON    2.908333
19         ORIGEN    3.105000
20      SPARKLING    3.695000
21          ANGEL    3.695000
22           BRUT    3.105000
23           12.0    3.105000
24     06BOTELLAS    3.695000
25            750    2.861667
26     CHARDONNAY    2.375000
27          PINOT    2.445000
28           NOIR    2.445000
29          EXTRA    2.375000
30             BR    2.375000
31           UVA,    2.375000
32  GR.ALC.12.80,    2.375000
33           VOL.    2.375000
34           0.46    2.375000
35     G/L.,CAJAS    2.375000
36              6    2.445000
37      BOLTELLAS    2.375000
38             GA    2.515000
39             AV    2.515000
40           0.45    2.515000
41       BOTELLAS    2.515000
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think I didn't explain myself correctly, sorry. The trouble I'm having is related to get the average price for each word. For example, if the word "orange" is present in the first and the second sentence of your example, that the dataframe WORD would store the value 1500 associated to the word "orange".

Comment: So you want the store the mean in the `words` dataframe?

Comment: Exactly! as a way of finding out if the pressence of a word in the sentence is associated with a higher or lower price than the average (for example, one would expect that some product that includes "premium" in its description would have a higher price than one that does not)

Comment: And it is possible that in one sentence there are multiple words present of the `words` dataframe?

Comment: absolutely, there will always be multiple words present for each text, as the WORDS dataframe is made of every unique word that are found in the TEXT column of the PRICES dataframe

Comment: Is it possible that you use my `pd.DataFrame` code above and create example dataframes which represent your problem. This way I can create an answer, else Im sure I miss something. Also it's not best practice to add data as a picture since we cannot copy and paste a picture in our IDE.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the inconvenience, I updated the edit with the sample dataframes

Comment: Thank you! It certainly works with the example, however it throws an "nothing to repeat at position 64924" error with the whole dataframe, but I think that's probably something about the data itself. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check for `NaN` after the `str.extractall`

Comment: I tried prices['TEXT']=prices['TEXT'].fillna('missing')
words['WORD']=words['WORD'].fillna('missing'), but didn't seem to work. Anyway, I'm sure your answer solves the problem, so I'll select it as the best answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212294/discussion-between-gustavo-moreno-and-erfan).